Is it okay not to use infinitive when referring to an idiom (or some other pharse)?
I saw a sentence in my textbook:
I think the moral of the story is let the buyer beware.
"Let the buyer beware" is an idiom, I wonder is it okay to insert it directly into the sentence without being transformed into an infinitive..
I think
I think the moral of the story is to let the buyer beware.
and
I think the moral of the story is "let the buyer beware". (with the quotation mark)
are correct but the original one is not. Am I correct?

You are absolutely right: the first is not grammatically correct (but might well be used in informal conversation), and the others are correct in any situation.

@JavaLatte Okay, thank you!
